# Ansible ignores condition in playbook

Tags: ansible

I've some trouble using when conditions when using ansible. There are five host groups with different hosts. Somehow ansible ignores the condition and still tries to run the task despite it is not in the condition. See example:

Inventory.yml

```
[devices]
dev1 ansible_host=10.0.0.1
 
[router]
router ansible_host=10.1.1.8
 
[hostsA]
hostA1 ansible_host=10.1.1.9
 
[hosts]
host1 ansible_host=10.2.1.9
host2 ansible_host=10.1.1.7

[groupB]
hostB1 ansible_host=10.1.1.5
```

install_packages.yml

```
-name: Install packages for devices and router
pip:
  req: ~/requirements.txt
when: "'devices' and 'router' in group_names"
 
-name: Install packages for host2
pip:
  req: ~/requirements.txt
when: "'host2' in group_names"
```

If I execute `ansible-playbook rollout.yaml -i inv.yml --limit="host2"`
it still tries to execute first task instead of skipping it (as intended). Does anyone know why and what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the condition

```yaml
      when:
        - "'devices' in group_names"
        - "'router' in group_names"
```

This is the same

```yaml
      when: "'devices' in group_names and 'router' in group_names"
```

---

If you want to test more groups it's more efficient creating a list e.g. `my_groups`. Find a list of common groups ([intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory)) and compare the number of items e.g.

```yaml
      when: my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length == my_groups|length
      vars:
        my_groups: [devices, router]
```

---

Q: **"*Ansible is skipping the tasks for every host.*"**

A: This is correct. Quoting from [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

> "*group_names: List of groups the current host is part of*"

In your inventory, none of the hosts is a member of both `devices` and `router`. As a result, the condition always fails. For example

```yaml
- hosts: router,dev1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: group_names
    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when:
        - "'devices' in group_names"
        - "'router' in group_names"
    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when: "'devices' in group_names and 'router' in group_names"

    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when: my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length == my_groups|length
      vars:
        my_groups: [devices, router]
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [router,dev1] *****************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [router] => 
  group_names:
  - router
ok: [dev1] => 
  group_names:
  - devices

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
skipping: [router]
skipping: [dev1]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
skipping: [router]
skipping: [dev1]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
skipping: [router]
skipping: [dev1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the way you and @larsks proposed, but now ansible is skipping the tasks for every host

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that your conditional statement doesn't do what you think it does. When you write:

```
"'devices' and 'router' in group_names"
```

You have effectively written:

```
('devices') and ('router' in group_names)
```

And since a non-zero string evaluates as boolean `true`, that translates to:

```
(true) and ('router' in group_names)
```

You can write instead:

```
when: 'devices' in group_names and 'router' in group_names
```

Or:

```
when:
  - 'devices' in group_names
  - 'router' in group_names
```

Answer (score -3):

So thanks for your help and hints I managed to fix the issue by using

`when: inventory_hostname == "device" or  inventory_hostname == "router"`.

I will try the other solutions for a more persistence or efficient solution

Comment: There is no host `device` in your inventory. `device` is the name of the group.